# Eclipse :JPA in Dynamic Web Project

Tags: jpa, import, jar

In eclipse, I created a JPA project with my entities and repository's.

Now I want to create a Dynamic web project with my servlets and jsp's.

How do I get both to work with each other?

I would say make a jar from my JPA project and import it in the Dynamic Web Project where I load it on the build path.

I tried this but I get a "The import ...... cannot be resolved" error

Is there a specific location I need to place this Jar?

Comment: It should work if you have added it to the build path correctly.
Add the jar to the build path and also tick mark it in Order and export tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by adding the jar in the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.  You don't need to add to the build path, just place your jar's here and your IDE will use them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add it as a jar , add in build path as **Reference Project**